# The string cmd enclosed by double quotes in bash commandline

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am a beginner of bash. I encounter a problem like this:

```
   $ "make -p"
```

when I type the above in bash command line, there is nothing to happen, no error, no result msg.

I have searched double quotes syntax of bash in many websites. All of these materials give similar interpretation as below:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html
and give examples like:

```
echo "argument"
```

I do not find something like `"echo argument"`. Moreover, I find a strange difference between bash command line and bash scripts.

If I type a non-existing command in command line:

```
$ "holy shit"
$ "look that"
```

there is nothing to happen. But if I type it in bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash  
"holy shit"  
"look that"
```

and execute this script, an error msg will be throw out:

```
$ ./myshell   
./myshell: line 2: holy shit: command not found  
./myshell: line 3: look that: command not found
```

Would someone can help give a detailed interpretation about the effect of double quotes when they enclosed the whole command?
Why there is no output in command-line? 
Why it is different between command line and scripts?

Comment: I am using bash and typing "make -p" in my console results in "make -p : commande introuvable", just like in scripts. Maybe it comes from your shell options (type "help set", without the double quotes hehehe)

Comment: When you start a line with "make -p", you instract the shell to search a command with exactly this name (i.e. m,a,k,e,space,dash,p). Since you don't have a command with this name in your path, you get the error message "command not found". The double quotes instruct the shell to regard the space and the '-p' as part of the command name.

Comment: @user1934428 But why there is not any error msg output in commandline if "shell to search a command with exactly this name (i.e. m,a,k,e,space,dash,p)"? I try `"cd home"`, nothing output; `"cd /home"`, output:  `bash: cd /home: No such file or directory`. How does the shell interpret it?

Comment: @ Pawamoy Maybe there is some special configure in my bash, I will try to find that. Thanks a lot~

Comment: @kenshion: You *do* get an error message. If I enter `"cd home"` (with the incorrect codes included), I get, as expected, the error message `bash: cd home: command not found`. I don't think this is different on your system. If it is, I would like to see a screenshot.

Comment: @user1934428 I have uploaded a pic in this site `http://i65.tinypic.com/14wyc12.png`. If you can browse it , you could obviously find the difference between our system.

Comment: @kenshion: I now see what you mean. Since my response to this is a bit longer, I will post it as an answer, not as a comment. Stand by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter a command `foo`, the shell searches the directories listed in your `PATH` variable until it finds a command of this name. If there is none, you get the error message *command not found*.

If you enter a command, which contains at least one slash - for example `./foo` or `foo/bar` -, the shell does *not* search the PATH, but assumes that you have already entered the correct path to your command. If it does not exist, you get the error message *No such file or directory*.

In your case,

```
 "cd home"
```

searches for a file with name *`cd home`* somewhere along your `PATH`, but there is no file of this name, and you get *command not found*. If you enter

```
"cd /home"
```

the shell bypasses PATH-search and assumes, that there exists a directory named *`cd`* (i.e. the 3 letters c,d,space) in your current directory, and below it a file named home, with x-bit set. There is no such file (and no such directory) on your system, and you get the error message *No such file or directory*.

If you are in the mood of experimenting around, you could try the following:

```
mydir="cd "
mkdir "$mydir"
echo "echo Hello Stranger" >"$mydir/home"
chmod +x "$mydir/home"
"cd /home"
```

This should print *Hello Stranger*. Pay attention that in the assignment to *mydir*, there must be a single space between the *cd* and the closing quote.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why there is no error msg `"command not found"` as you said when I type "cd home" in my system?

Comment: This would mean that on your system, you somehow managed to create a command with this name. You can verify it like this: First, in your shell, enter again `"cd home"`, to see that you really don't get an error manage *right now* (as the situation might be different from the time you took the screen shot). If there is no error, enter the command `type "cd home"`. This should output a message explaining what bash thinks about this command. In my case for example, the `type` command outputs *cd home not found*.

Comment: I try what you suggested. Enter `"cd home"`,nothing output. Enter `type "cd home"`, output `bash: type: cd home: not found`. It is so strange in my system that I can't find any reasonable explanation.

Comment: Now things get really interesting. To narrow it down, do the following: First enter a subshell with the command `bash --noprofile --norc` . Then, do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` . Next do a `set -x`. Finally, do a `"cd home"` again. Finally, type `exit`. Make a screenshot.

Comment: I did what you said, the screenshot link is `http://i63.tinypic.com/2sbqxip.jpg`. The error msg finally appeared. There should be some special  configure in my bash...

Comment: I thought so. To see what is going on, you could first just run the trace (`set -x`) in your original setting. Then, you can check your shell settings (shopt). You can try it in a subshell with *either* `--noprofile` or `--norc`, but not both (to narrow down, where the configuration happens).

Comment: I `set -x` in my original shell, the output is   `+ 'cd home'  
+ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'  
+ /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- cd home  
+ return 127  
`. Then I type `/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- cd home`, nothing output. I think the cause may be "command-not-found" can not output msg. I will try to find why. By the way,  I set `bash --noprofile`,no err msg output when typing `"cd home"`. But err msg can appear if setting `bash --norc` and typing "cd home". There should be something special in rc files.  Thanks a lot~~

Comment: As you correctly understand, this must then be caused by some setting in your `.bashrc`, which should then be trivial to locate (even maybe it is a bit tedious). I seems that you have some autocorrection feature, which triggers the `command-not-found` python program, instead of creating the error message ... see also [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/why-is-this-python-error-message-generated-whenever-i-type-a-nonsense-command). This brings us back to my previous comment: Did you check your shell options (`shopt`)?

Comment: sorry for weekend leave. I checked `/usr/lib/command-not-found` and find an expression `if len(args) == 1:` . By adding print before and after this expression, I'm sure that this condition expression cause typing two and more unknown words command enclosed by double quotes in command line resulting in nothing. Also I checked my ubuntu version "Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS" . In newer version, I found `command-not-found` file has been changed to fix this bug. Now I would try to find which autocorrection feature bringing in this python procedure rather than what did in native shell.

Comment: In /etc/bash.bashrc , I found that `if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then...`, this brings in python procedure. All distinguished -_- ~.~ ! Thanks again. This problem can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes mean it is a string. You can do something like:

```
echo "Hello everybody"
```

either at the command line or the shell. Sometimes when people put stuff in quotes. you are supposed to replace what is in quotes with your own variable (removing the quotes), and sometimes people put quotes around the whole command you are supposed to type to show the what exactly you should type. For your example of "make -p" just type it without the quotes and it should work in both the command line and as a script.

Comment: No, the double quotes mean it is a single *word*, as defined by the shell. Everything in shell is a string, even something like `123`. That's why there are special arithmetic operators, to create a context where a number-like string is interpreted as a number.